# Crear una columna cuyos valores van en función de la presencia o no de un carácter dado en otra columna

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Esta es mi primera consulta en el portal así que ante todo gracias por su tiempo y sus respuestas. Tengo un dataframe similar a este que adjunto como ejemplo:

```
ID String_a
 0  A3-M3
 1  EJ-EK
 2  CK-CL 
 3  A3
 4  FM-FL
```

Lo que necesito es crear una columna nueva, o bien reemplazar la misma, según la siguiente lógica:

- Si el string tiene un caracter '3', me indique 'valor_3'
- Si el String tiene un caracter 'E', me indique 'valor_E'
- Para todo lo demás, me debe indicar 'valor_O'

He intentado usando if o la función replace, pero fallo en algo siempre.
Espero puedan ayudarme. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Roberto, bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Existe la posibilidad de que  una fila contenga 3 y E al mismo tiempo? Si es así, ¿Cuál debe ser la salida?

Comment: Hola, no. Los resultados son mutuamente excluyentes. Solo puede haber un 3 o una E en una fila. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Usar `str.replace` como planteas en este caso se complica por el hecho de que las cadenas que pueden presentar una `E` (por ejemplo) son heterogéneas.

Vamos a crear un ejemplo reproducible de partida:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": list(range(5)),
                   "String_a": ("A3-M3", "EJ-EK", "CK-CL", "A3", "FM-FL")
                   })
df.set_index("ID", inplace=True)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    String_a
> ID         
> 0     A3-M3
> 1     EJ-EK
> 2     CK-CL
> 3        A3
> 4     FM-FL
> ```

La aproximación más simple y creo que para este caso concreto la mejor es usar una función con condicionales tal y como planteabas en la pregunta y usar `pandas.DataFrame.apply` para crear la nueva columna:

```
def set_values(item):
    if "3" in item:
        return "valor_3"
    elif "E" in item:
        return "valor_E"
    return "valor_O"

df["Valor"] = df["String_a"].apply(set_values)
```

> 2.23 ms ± 120 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Existen otras posibilidades basadas en el uso de un filtro boleano para asignar los valores a las filas que corresponde, algunas de ellas que se me ocurren:

- Usar `pandas.Series.str.contains` a modo de filtro boleano:

  ```
  df["Valor"] = "valor_O" # Por defecto
  df.loc[df["String_a"].str.contains("3", regex=False, na=False), "Valor"] = 'valor_3'
  df.loc[df["String_a"].str.contains("E", regex=False, na=False), "Valor"] = 'valor_E'
  ```

  > 9.29 ms ± 273 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
- Usar `pandas.Series.str.contains` junto a `numpy.select`:

  ```
  condiciones = [df["String_a"].str.contains("3", regex=False, na=False),
                 df["String_a"].str.contains("E", regex=False, na=False)
                 ]
  valores = ['valor_3', 'valor_E']
  df["Valor"] = np.select(condiciones, valores, default='valor_0')
  ```

  > 4.68 ms ± 205 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
- Usar `numpy.vectorize` junto a función python y operador `in`

  ```
  f = np.vectorize(lambda cadena, caracter: caracter in cadena)
  df["Valor"] = "valor_O"
  df.loc[f(df["String_a"], "3"), "Valor"] = 'valor_3'
  df.loc[f(df["String_a"], "E"), "Valor"] = 'valor_E'
  ```

  > 5.04 ms ± 153 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
- Filtro boleano mediante listas:por compresión:

  ```
  df["Valor"] = "valor_O"
  df.loc[["3" in cadena for cadena in df["String_a"]], "Valor"] = 'valor_3'
  df.loc[["E" in cadena for cadena in df["String_a"]], "Valor"] = 'valor_E'
  ```

  > 5.85 ms ± 143 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Lo que aparece debajo de cada código es el tiempo de ejecución para una columna de 10000 items. Aparentemente, si no hay otra forma más eficiente que estúpidamente haya pasado por alto, por una vez  `apply` + python crudo ganan.

La salida en cualquier caso es:

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    String_a  Valor
> ID                  
> 0     A3-M3  valor_3
> 1     EJ-EK  valor_E
> 2     CK-CL  valor_O
> 3        A3  valor_3
> 4     FM-FL  valor_O
> ```

Comment: Me funcionó perfecto la función. No probé con las otras opciones pero seguramente son igual de buenas. Muchas gracias por la ayuda